# Is there a way to achieve outlets in next.js ? in regular react router i could use <outlet> to render child components

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Is there an implementation of router Outlet in next.js or similar ? I want to render child components on the same page using sub-routes, but I haven't been able to find anything for next.js that does the same.

Comment: Are you using the "pages" or "app" directory?

Comment: im still using pages, havent switched over to app directory

Answer (score 2):

Since you're not using Next.js 13+'s "app directory" there is no native way of handling templates/layouts. Instead you have to create your own layout system

Here's an example:

```
// /components/Layout.js
export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <main>
        <header>My Website</header>
        <article>{children}</article>
                {/*  ^ this is your "<Outlet>" */}
    </main>
  )
}
```

```
// /pages/blog/post1.jsx
import { Layout } from "@components/Layout";

export default function BlogPost1() {
  return (
    <Layout>
        <h1>Blog post 1!</h1>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

```
// /pages/blog/post2.jsx
import { Layout } from "@components/Layout";

export default function BlogPost2() {
  return (
    <Layout>
        <h1>Blog post 2!</h1>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

Don't take this example literally, in a real-world scenario you would use dynamic router like `[id].js`.

Comment: I understand dynamic router, my problem is I have a dashboard with a sidebar and i want to render components on the right side of the sidebar, depending on what i click, without rerendering. Also I am on next.js 13.4, I am in the middle of switching from pages to app directory

Comment: if that's your problem then my answer should work for that situation. React won't render parts that haven't changed, that's the whole point of a diffing algorithm. Making a custom layout is how it's been done before the app directory

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this,

**app/layout.js**

```
// - Applies to all routes
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        <Header />
        {children}
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

**app/dashboard/layout.js**

````
// - Applies to route segments in app/dashboard/*
export default function DashboardLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <DashboardSidebar />
      {children}
    </>
  );
}```

refer this,

[enter link description here][1][2]


  [1]: https://nextjs.org/blog/layouts-rfc
  [2]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69-mnojSa0M
````

Comment: OP is not using app dir